# Java Thread - Make a clock and own clock

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

So I'm starting to get really interested about Threads and how it works, Kinda amazing how it works but I just learned about it today and trying to make a program to work. So im trying to make a clock that gives me in a Jlabel a current clock which is right now and a Textfield where I enter the time by myself. so what I want to do is it should start by showing me the time, when pressing the button "Set time" it should change the time as I entered and go from there as a clock. [image: My GUI]

So my problem right now is that whenever I press the Set time now it changes for a second and then turn back to the current clock again. and I don't really know how to stop the first thread when pressing Set time (Which starts the second Thread)

However I think this is kinda simple but fun to work with,

EDIT: I Also found out that I will have a problem by counting when entering a own "clock". My code:

```
 public Clock() {
            initialize();
            Thread1();

        }

    .......


JButton btnSetTime = new JButton("Set time");
            btnSetTime.setBounds(474, 262, 89, 23);
            frame.getContentPane().add(btnSetTime);
            btnSetTime.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if(e.getSource() == btnSetTime) {
                        Thread2();

                    }

                }
            });
        }

        public void Thread2() {
            Thread t2 = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        for(;;) {
                            int hour = Integer.parseInt(tfhour.getText());
                            int minute = Integer.parseInt(tfminute.getText());
                            int second = Integer.parseInt(tfsecond.getText());

                            lblKlockan.setText(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
                            sleep(1000);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                }
            };t2.start();
        }

        public void Thread1() {
            Thread t1 = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        for(;;) {
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                            int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                            int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                            lblKlockan.setText(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
                            sleep(1000);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                }
            };t1.start();
        }
    }
```

So as I can see, the int hour = Integer.parseInt(tfhour.getText()); will probably not count as a Clock if I change to my own clock later on if i'm right? In that case, How can I fix it?

I hope I have all my problems out here in the post and I hope anyone here is willing to help me aswell :)

EDIT:

### To make it easier to see: [image]

EDIT PART 3:0
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a global variable to stop the thread 1, when the thread 2 starts. Here is an example,

```
//define a variable that controls the thread 1
static boolean clockSet = false;
```

Now thread 1 is written such as it runs only when the clockSet is false, that is clock not set by a click.

```
  Thread t1 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
           while(!clockSet){
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);                   
               lblKlockan.setText(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
               try {
              sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
   };
```

In your thread 2, set the clockSet to true, so the thread 1 will stop. I see you are just displaying the value entered, but not setting those on a Calendar object. So create a Calendar object in thread 2, set the user defined values, and increment the time after every second of sleep.

```
Thread t2 = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        clockSet = true;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(tfhour.getText()));
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(tfminute.getText()));
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, Integer.parseInt(tfsecond.getText()));
        while(true){                    
                int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);                   
               lblKlockan.setText(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
               try {
            sleep(1000);
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}
      }
     }
   };
```

Have fun..!

Comment: Oh thank you! Shouldn't it only go if you just add in the ActionListiner  `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == btnSetTime) {
     clockSet = true;`  in that case?

Comment: That will work as well, bottom line is, a variable should be there to control the life cycle of thread 1, just before you start thread 2.

Comment: Just to make sure you understand, a Thread in java can only be stopped based on a condition. So the run method has this 'while' loop to check for a flag and decides whether to continue or not.
See, I have logic in Thread 1 implementation to check for this flag. That flag needs to be set to true, whenever user clicks the button. That is all. Also, notice the Thread 2 implementation that uses same Calendar object in the loop.

Comment: okey So I did what you said but getting some troubles. so whenever I press now the Button, it gives me a freezing number and just ends there. What could be the problem?

Comment: Thats why you used the boolean, so if its false it should give us the current time, when clicking the button, it should change the boolean value to True and it SHOULD but doesnt :( give us the value that I entered, instead its just freezing which is kinda strange?

Comment: Did you modify the thread 2 implementation as I have? It looks like your thread 1 is stopping, check the logic in thread 2.

Comment: I think I know what I did wrong, I forgot to add in the ActionListiner `clockSet = true;
     Thread2();` and now it works!! The only problem is when I enter value 11 it gives me 23 which should be 11 haha :P but its because you had HOUR_OF_DAY instead:)

But if you have time, Could you explain to me how you were thinking about this? why did you use the boolean?

Comment: but I tried, if I changed the value and want to change it again, it comes again the same problem. Which will loop over and over haha. Check the EDIT for Gif. picture

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94751/discussion-between-weinthis-and-droidman).

Comment: This helped me alot! Found out that I needed to make a variable that  checks if Thread2 is running, if its running then dont run it again and let it run. Anyways if someone needs more help about this, feel free to write here! and I will take it over! However, big thumps for everyone and also special thanks for @Droidman that helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you see the code

```
try {
                        for(;;) {
                            int hour = Integer.parseInt(tfhour.getText());//this one
                            int minute = Integer.parseInt(tfminute.getText());//and this one
                            int second = Integer.parseInt(tfsecond.getText());//and this too

                            lblKlockan.setText(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
                            sleep(1000);
                        }
```

---

you are setting hour, minute & second each and every time inside the for loop. So the clock is reseting.

Make them to get initialize only once, i.e. take them out of the loop.

---

Further this code

```
for(;;) {
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                            int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                            int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                            lblKlockan.setText(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
                            sleep(1000);
                        }
```

is making your timer work as clock and not a timer because after 1 sec. the hour, minute & second are set to the values according to the time you get from Calendar.

Due to this your code will work as a clock that show the current time.

Comment: Hmm, I only removed the for loop and it was the same results, Because the other thread is using a for(;;) aswell. BUT without it, the clock wont count then. So what it possible wrong?

Comment: Like I have to make the Thread 2 take over the Thread 1 somehow, or maybe stop Thread 1 and make Thread 2 work when pressing the button?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. so the Thread 1 is going like the clock meanwhile the Thread 2 only has the values that I have put in the TextField which I have to make it count somehow (Thats the problem where I don't know) and also make so it takes over the from Thread 1 so it shows up in my GUI the new Clock. If you understand what I mean :)? @shivam7357

Comment: tell me what do you want your code to do exactly: a clock or a timer?

Comment: A clock. So first it starts of as a Clock, and if I put values in my GUI etc. 12:12:12. It should update the clock to 12:12:12 (With thread 2) and then work like a clock. which will be 12:12:13...12:12:14..... and so on

Comment: so basically before you enter the values the code will show the current time. After you enter some values it will become up-timer??
Is it?

Comment: Yeah something like that. as you say, When running the program at the start, it gives you the current Time. when entering values it will become a kinda up-timer which doesn't have a stop but will work almost like clock but not giving you the current time:)

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94747/discussion-between-weinthis-and-shivam7357).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you don't need the second thread at all. What I would do in this case is create three `Int` fields, hour-, minute- and second-offset, which you change when the button is pressed to, for example, `hourOffset =  Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY - Integer.parseInt(tfhour.getText())%24;` (example for the hours). Than you just need to add the offset to the time in thread1, which allways works since you start with 0 as offset.